# Car rentals in Spain

Tags: car-rentals, automobiles, spain

we want to hire a car for 10 days in Madrid. Since we have bad experiences with car rentals (especially those cheap ones), we would like to ask you for your experiences with Dollar and Enterprise car rentals. They seems more trustworthy than Goldcar or Firefly and their prices are not as high as Hertz or Avis.

Are they trustworthy?

Answer (score 2):

I rented a car from Atesa (I think they have a contract with Enterprise) in Bilbao, drove it for three days, and returned it to their garage in Barcelona. As long as you have no damage to the car when you return and the appropriate amount of gas needed, you should be fine. Make sure that you read the terms of your rental to make sure of what condition you must return your car in, because they check every part of the car when you return it. They will also give you a folder when they give you your car, make sure you have that and all paperwork inside when you return it.